# Do non-Kanto Pokemon evolve before getting the National Dex in a randomised Fire Red?

Tags: emulation, pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green

I am currently playing a rom of Fire Red with randomised encounters and trainer Pokemon.

I have captured a few Pokemon not included in the Kanto Pokedex and none have reached a high enough level to evolve.
I recall that Golbat cannot evolve into Crobat before obtaining the National Pokedex, my question is whether for example my Shuppet (purchased in place of the Mt Moon Magikarp) will evolve into Banette at the proper level or if it will be halted from evolving like Golbat into Crobat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need the National Dex to evolve Shuppet.

Depending on the randomizer you use, you should have had an option to enable the national dex. The randomizer may include a tooltip on why that is important. In the Universal Pokemon Randomizer, this is found under the Misc Tweaks tab.

[image]

This is supported by other users reporting being unable to evolve pokemon in the National Dex in threads on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/15da6f/my_treecko_cant_evolve_im_using_a_randomised_rom/) or [yahoo](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120131100929AAQ6aQ7).